# React performance taking a hit with hundreds of elements

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a React app that polls a server for console entries (eg: a web version of a tail'd log). The reducer stores the elements in state (using redux) and then renders them.

At around 300-400 entries, the whole page starts to slow down substantially.

I am already using `react-list` to render the items only when they're visible on screen, so I don't think it's the number of DOM elements causing the speed issue.

- Why does this happen?
- How do I go about handling the speed issue?
- How do I help track this issue down?

Edit #1: Here's the code of the view

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactList from 'react-list';
import reactMixin from 'react-mixin';
import PureRender from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import css from './styles/feed.scss';

export class Entry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getContent = this.getContent.bind(this);
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  getContent() {
    return <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.entry.message}}></div>;
  }
  render () {
    var className = classnames("type", this.props.entry.type);
    return (
      <div className="entry">
        <div className={className}>{this.props.entry.type}</div>
        <div className="message">
          {this.getContent()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Entry.propTypes = {
  entry: React.PropTypes.shape({
    type:React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    message:React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    id:React.PropTypes.id
  }).isRequired
};

export class Feed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    this.shouldScrollBottom = true;
  }
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (this.shouldScrollBottom) {
      var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
      node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight
    }
  }
  componentWillUpdate() {
    var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    this.shouldScrollBottom = node.scrollTop + node.offsetHeight === node.scrollHeight;
  }
  renderItem(e, key) {
    let entry = this.props.entries[e];
    return <Entry entry={entry} key={key} visible={this.props.filter.indexOf(entry.type)!==-1 ? true : false }/>;
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="console">
        <ReactList
          itemRenderer={this.renderItem}
          length={this.props.entries.length}
          type='variable'
          useTranslate3d={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Feed.propTypes = {
  entries: React.PropTypes.array,
  filter: React.PropTypes.array
};
Feed.defaultProps ={
  entries: [],
  filter: []
}
reactMixin(Feed.prototype, PureRender);
```

Comment: It would help if you show us some code...

Comment: You may find why it happens if you profile it (using chrome profiler for example: timeline & CPU Profile is usually sufficient). PS: say Hi to Andrew and Simon from Ivan ;-)

Comment: since you're not altering any attribs/props from it, i would move the code in componentWillUpdate to componentDidUpdate so that your dom mess in one stage instead of two, and you can cache some of the expensive dom values like `node` and `scrollHeight`. you can also move a scroll "all the way down" with  `node.scrollTop = 9e9;` instead of measuring, which is expensive.

Comment: @dandavis why that magic number `9e9`? I googled it. It's the scientific notation of 9,000,000,000. There seems to be some convention about it like `x|0` to get a 32-bit value out of x, but why?? Just being cool?

Comment: simple: 9e9 is guaranteed to be greater than the scroll height, unless, well, yeah, it's guaranteed. if you over-shoot the height, it just scrolls to the bottom. This will likely be much faster than trying to determine the height and scroll pos from userland JS.